# Having R abbreviate long, user-provided character input for function argument

Tags: r, function, text, character

## Background:

I have an R function called `abs`. The function has only one argument called `main.name`. User of this function provides a character type name in quotation marks (e.g., `"Length of Residence"`), and the function `abs` uses this user-provided name as the main title of a simple plot.

## Question

A user may provide a very long name (e.g., `"Oral Language Ability of Minors"`). To overcome this problem:

I was wondering if there is a way **when** a user provides **a `main.name` that is more than 2 words, R would pick the first character of each word and make an "Abbreviation" of that `main.name`?**

For example after such an aberration, `"Oral Language Ability of Minors"` becomes "`OLAOM`".

```
abs = function (main.name) {

plot(rnorm(1e2), main = main.name)

} 

abs ("Oral Language Ability of Minors")
```

Comment: You might find the built-in `abbreviate` function useful. If you want more flexibility, you can create your own function. For example, to capture just the first letter of each word: `paste(sapply(strsplit(x, " "), substr, 1, 1), collapse="")`, where `x` is your string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
rename = function(string){
  tmp = strsplit(string, " ")

  if(length(tmp[[1]]) > 2){
    return(toupper(paste(unlist(lapply(tmp, substring, 1, 1)),collapse = "")))
  }else{
    return(paste(unlist(tmp), collapse = " "))
  }
}

> rename("Oral Language Ability of Minors")
[1] "OLAOM"

> rename("Oral Language")
[1] "Oral Language"
```